# sp-consensus-babe issue key `branch` is ignored for dependency (sp-consensus-babe)

Tags: substrate-node-template

Hi i am trying to use the `sp-consensus-babe` but I am having issues when I'm running the command

**`command: cargo build --release`**

The issue that I am receiving is this

> error: failed to load manifest for workspace member
> `/Users/abubakarmujahid/Desktop/Substrate/substrate-node-template/node`
>
> Caused by:   failed to load manifest for dependency
> `node-template-runtime`
>
> Caused by:   failed to parse manifest at
> `/Users/abubakarmujahid/Desktop/Substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime/Cargo.toml`
>
> Caused by:   key `branch` is ignored for dependency
> (sp-consensus-babe).

But I have defined the dependency correctly in cargo.toml. I have described it in the following way.

```
sp-consensus-babe = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
```

Can anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in the dependency instead of the path = to I have to mention the git=

**Previously it was**

```
sp-consensus-babe = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
```

**But it has to be in this manner**

```
sp-consensus-babe = { version = "0.10.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42" }
```